# Se duplican los objetos al guardarlos en un ArrayList en Java

Tags: java, arraylist

Llevo poco tiempo programando en Java y me he encontrado con un error que no soy capaz de resolver. Os detallo el problema:

Tengo en una BD de MySQL la información de los empleados que forman cada departamento. Estoy a través de un método recuperar estos datos y almacenarlos en un ArrayList para luego pintarlos en un JTable.

Cuando recupero la información de la BD los datos son correctos pero según los voy insertando en el ArrayList me machaca la información anterior con lo último leído.
Os muestro el código que he realizado y un ejemplo del resultado al ejecutarlo:

```
public static ArrayList<Empleado> getEmpleados_Centro_Linea_Celda(String inCentro, String inLinea, String inCelda)
{
    ArrayList<Empleado> **empleados** = new ArrayList<Empleado>();

    ConexionMySQL conn = new ConexionMySQL();
    String sqlBusq  = "select NumEmpl, Nombre, Apellidos"
                    + " from gestionEquipos.Empleado where FK_gestEq_Centro = ? and FK_gestEq_Linea = ? and FK_gestEq_Celda = ?";
    Connection cn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try
    {
        // Utilizamos la conexión creada
        cn = conn.getConexion();

        //Preparamos la query y pasamos el nº de empleado del empleado recibido
        pstmt = cn.prepareStatement(sqlBusq);
        pstmt.setString(1, inCentro);
        pstmt.setString(2, inLinea);
        pstmt.setString(3, inCelda);

        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next())    
        {
            int tmpNEmpl        = 0;
            String tmpNombre    = "";
            String tmpApellidos = "";

            tmpNEmpl     = rs.getInt("NumEmpl");
            tmpNombre    = rs.getString("Nombre");
            tmpApellidos = rs.getString("Apellidos");

            empleados.add(new Empleado(tmpNEmpl, tmpNombre, tmpApellidos));
            pintaArrayList(empleados);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        String strAux = "queryEmpleados.getEmpleados_Centro_Linea_Celda(" + inCentro + "." + inLinea + "." + inCelda + "):problema en la consulta." + ex.getMessage(); 
        Utiles.escribeLog("d:/Logs/log_consultaEmpl.txt", strAux);

        ex.printStackTrace();

        return(null);
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            cn.close();             
        }
        catch (Exception ex2)
        {
            String strAux = "queryEmpleados.getEmpleados_Centro_Linea_Celda:problema al cerrar la conexión con la BD." + ex2.getMessage(); 
            Utiles.escribeLog("d:/Logs/log_consultaEmpl.txt", strAux);

            ex2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return(empleados);
}

private static void pintaArrayList(ArrayList<Empleado> inEmpleados)
{
    Iterator<Empleado> iter = inEmpleados.iterator();
    Empleado tmpEmpl;
    while(iter.hasNext())
    {
        tmpEmpl = iter.next();
        System.out.println("pintaArrayList-iterator(" + tmpEmpl.getNumEmpl() + " -" + tmpEmpl.Nombre() + " " + tmpEmpl.getApellidos() + ")");
    }
}
```

Con el método "**pintaArrayList**" muestro por pantalla lo que tiene almacenado el ArrayList y me encuentro con el siguiente resultado:

```
pintaArrayList-iterator(235 - Andrea XXXX YYYYY)
pintaArrayList-iterator(242 - David XXXX YYYY)
pintaArrayList-iterator(242 - David XXXX YYYY)
pintaArrayList-iterator(239 - Jose Manuel XXXX YYYY)
pintaArrayList-iterator(239 - Jose Manuel XXXX YYYY)
pintaArrayList-iterator(239 - Jose Manuel XXXX YYYY)
```

He estado buscando alternativas pero no logro ninguna que no machaque los datos.
¿Qué puedo hacer?

Muchas gracias.

Esta es la clase empleado:

```
public class Empleado {
private static int    numEmpl;
private static String nombre;
private static String apellidos;
...
```

Comment: No veo en el código motivo para causar el problema... ¿estás seguro que no tienes datos duplicados en la tabla?

Comment: Por favor, aclarate. O se duplican o se machacan. En la función creas el ArrayList nuevo cada vez, así que es normal que te guarde en el array lo que tengas en la base de datos cada vez que llamas a esa función.

Comment: Hola, los datos no están duplicados en la BD, he confirmado con println que lo que se recupera de la BD está bien.

Comment: @SuperG280, según voy añadiendo en el arraylist se machaca la información que hay almacenada en el ArrayList. Lo que estaba planteando en esta función es crear un arraylist, incluir la información de la BD y devolverlo. ¿Qué es lo que no está bien?

Comment: Vale, ya lo entiendo, pero no encuentro el motivo. Te recomiendo poner un punto de ruptura ahí, cuando vas a hacer el add de cada elemento y ejecutarlo paso a paso a ver qué recibes de la base de datos y qué estás creando en cada vuelta del bucle.

Comment: Pon la clase Empleado... ¿No será que has declarado los atributos como *static*?

Comment: Hola, he puesto la parte de la clase empleado, efectivamente los atributos son **static**, ¿es ese el problema?

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Efectivamente ese era el problema, los atributos de la clase Empleado las tenía puestas como static y por eso a todos los objetos que creaba les asignaba el mismo valor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucioné con la ayuda del [comentario que ha hecho SJuan76](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/363426/se-duplican-los-objetos-al-guardarlos-en-un-arraylist-en-java/363439#comment652618_363426).

El problema estaba en que los atributos de la clase Empleado las tenía declarados como `static` y eso hacía que se duplicaran los valores. Quitando en la declaración de variables el atributo `static` se soluciona el problema:

```
public class Empleado {
    private int    numEmpl;
    private String nombre;
    private String apellidos;
    ...
```